# Python Code unable to find dependencies with launchd plist Mac OS 10.8.5

Tags: python, macos, dependencies, launchd

I have a python script which scrapes a website for information every 5 minutes all for personal use.  The script works fine when executed from the terminal, however when it is executed by launchctl it gives an error as if the installed python module cannot be found:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Application Support/PythonDaemons/TrafficScraper.py", line 36, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

I know there are some special considerations because the system is executing it not the user however I don't know where to start on fixing it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I added the PYTHONPATH environment variable to the plist and the application worked.